# TransactionScope committing on each loop

Tags: vb.net, transactions

Please see the code below:

```
Private Sub TransactionExample3()
        Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand, objCommand2 As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Dim objCon2 As SqlConnection
        Dim id As Integer
        Dim list As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
        Try
            _ConString = "Data Source=databaseserver;Initial Catalog=Person;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
            list.Add(1)
            list.Add(2)
            list.Add(3)

            For Each i As Integer In list
                Using trans = New TransactionScope()
                    objCon2 = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
                    objCon2.Open()
                    objCommand2 = New SqlCommand()
                    objCommand2.Connection = objCon2
                    Using objCon2
                        objCommand2.CommandText = "UPDATE Person SET forenames = @forenames WHERE " & _
                            " Reference = @Reference "
                        objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forenames", i + 1)
                        objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reference", i)
                        objCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        objCommand2.Parameters.Clear()
                    End Using
                    trans.Complete()
                End Using
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

        End Try

    End Sub
```

This code works i.e. on each loop the changes are committed to the database.

Now please see the code below:

```
Private Sub TransactionExample3()
        Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand, objCommand2 As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Dim objCon2 As SqlConnection
        Dim id As Integer
        Try
            _ConString = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Person;User ID=Username;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
            objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
            objCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT top 10 * from Person")
            objCommand.Connection = objCon
            objCon.Open()
            objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
            Do While objDR.Read
                objCon2 = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
                objCon2.Open()
                Using trans = New TransactionScope()
                    objCommand2 = New SqlCommand()
                    objCommand2.Connection = objCon
                    Using objCon2
                        objCommand2.CommandText = "UPDATE Person SET forenames = @forenames WHERE " & _
                            " Reference = @Reference "
                        objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forenames", objDR("Reference") + 10)
                        objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reference", objDR("Reference"))
                        objCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        objCommand2.Parameters.Clear()
                    End Using
                End Using
            Loop
            objDR.Close() 'line 16
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

        End Try

    End Sub
```

In the second code exherpt, the scope is not complete (scope.complete), however the results are still committed to the database on each iteration of the while loop.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first loop the opening of the TransactionScope is before the opening of the connection. In the second one is after. The connection is not enlisted in the Transaction and thus every command executes without being held by a transaction.

Try to switch these lines

```
Do While objDR.Read
    Using trans = New TransactionScope()
       objCon2 = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
       objCon2.Open()
       .....
```

Now you need the call to  trans.Complete()

```
Private Sub TransactionExample3()
    Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
    Dim objCommand As SqlCommand, objCommand2 As SqlCommand
    Dim objCon As SqlConnection
    Dim objCon2 As SqlConnection
    Dim id As Integer
    _ConString = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Person;User ID=Username;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    Using objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
        objCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT top 10 * from Person")
        objCommand.Connection = objCon
        objCon.Open()
        objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Using trans = New TransactionScope()
        Using objCon2 = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
            objCon2.Open()
            Do While objDR.Read
                objCommand2 = New SqlCommand()
                objCommand2.Connection = objCon
                Using objCon2
                    objCommand2.CommandText = "UPDATE Person SET forenames = @forenames WHERE " & _
                        " Reference = @Reference "
                    objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forenames", objDR("Reference") + 10)
                    objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reference", objDR("Reference"))
                    objCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    objCommand2.Parameters.Clear()
                End Using
            Loop
            objDR.Close() 'line 16
        End Using
        trans.Complete()
        End Using    
    End Using
End Sub
```

I suggest to move the Transaction and Connection opening outside the loop and call the Complete and destroy the connection after the foreach loop, if I understand your code correctly you update one record at each loop and so the Transaction makes sense only if you want to update all of your records  or none. Another minor optimization could be to move the creation of the SqlCommand and the Parameters outside the loop. You update just the parameters value inside the loop without destroying and rebuilding the parameter collection at each loop

Comment: Thanks. That was it +1. is it bad practice to put TransactionScope inside a while loop i.e. scope.complete on each iteration?

Comment: Yes, what is the scope to start a transaction if you just update one record? Why open the connection at each loop? Put everything before the loop and complete only after exiting the loop

Comment: The reason it is done on each iteration is because the default isolation level of TransactionScope is Serializable, which locks the entire table.  Do I just change the isolation level to readcommitted?

Comment: @w0051977: _"That was it"_ means you should also accept the answer ;)

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing the context in which you operate. You take TOP 10 records to update the table, so this should be really fast. But if you don't require a rollback in case of failure (because you are able to restart the operation from the point of interruption) then why do you use a Transaction at all?

Comment: Thanks.  The code in the above was there as an example only.  The actual application can take five minutes to run.

Comment: The reason I want to commit on each loop is so that the transaction does not lock the table for too long? Do I need to change the isolation level of transaction scope I wander?

Comment: I am not an expert of this matter, but what do you gain using a Transaction in a scenario where you update just one record?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  The production code updates more than one table (four).  What is wrong with putting a TransactionScope statement inside a while loop (in your first comment you answered: "Yes").  This is my last question.

Comment: My comment refers to the current code. In this example the TransactionScope is opened inside the loop, then ONE record is updated, then the Scope is confirmed. My objection reside in this fact because if the update fails you don't have to rollback anything. The only record affected is the one failing. Transactions should be used to guarantee the atomicity of a series of Updates/Insert/deletes to the database. The example has no problem with the atomicity of the update (it is just one record per loop) so it doesn't need the transaction. Of course if your real code is different.....